# Android Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with tiny bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I'm creating the drawables for an activity's Buttons in java code. They only consist of two colors, other on top and other in the bottom, and the division point has to be adjusted according to the user's score.

I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even after scaling the drawables down to 1 by 50 pixels, which is good enough resolution for the actual bitmap, as it would be scaled up to match the button's size.

Is this about a memory leak? All instructions I found were about downloadable images that might actually be too big for the application to handle but I doubt 50 pixels in an image is too much...

My current code (createButton gets called 12 times during onStart()):

```
private void createButton(int points, int id, int color1, int color2, int maxPoints){
    findViewById(id).setBackground(createDrawable(color1, color2, points / maxPoints));
}

private Drawable createDrawable(int color1, int color2, float fillRatio){

    int width = 1;
    int height = 50;

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    Paint p = new Paint();

    //fill upper part
    p.setColor(color1);
    c.drawRect(0f, height * (1 - fillRatio), width, height, p);

    //fill lower part
    p.setColor(color2);
    c.drawRect(0f, 0f, width, height * (1 - fillRatio), p);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
}
```

I already tried `b.recycle()`, by replacing the return statement of the createDrawable method with

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
b.recycle();
return bd;
```

But that didn't help.
Also tried using the actual button size for the bitmap size, in case it was a scaling error but as this is called during onStart, `button.getWidth()` and `button.getHeight()` return zeroes.

EDIT:

Tried RGB_565 but it didn't work and I'll probably use alpha values later anyways. Error trace, if it does help:

```
... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myfirm.project, PID: 29992
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:701)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:526)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3453)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1893)
   at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ResourcesCompat.java:55)
   at com.apliki.palikat.MenuActivity.createButtons(MenuActivity.java:112)
   at com.apliki.palikat.MenuActivity.onStart(MenuActivity.java:73)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5592)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2414)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

Ok now it's inexplicably working. No idea why, I've made quite a few changes to other part of the app after just disabling the button creation. Now I tried again and it just works. Tried a few times too. o.O 
I'll update any findings here.

Comment: Where do you get the OOM? Is it reproducable during bitmap allocation or is does it happen in some independent part of the code?

Comment: are you doing this createDrawable in a separate thread or the main thread?

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 to RGB565:

```
private void createButton(int points, int id, int color1, int color2, int maxPoints){
        findViewById(id).setBackground(createDrawable(color1, color2, points / maxPoints));
}

private Drawable createDrawable(int color1, int color2, float fillRatio){

    int width = 1;
    int height = 50;

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    //fill upper part
    p.setColor(color1);
    c.drawRect(0f, height * (1 - fillRatio), width, height, p);

    //fill lower part
    p.setColor(color2);
    c.drawRect(0f, 0f, width, height * (1 - fillRatio), p);

    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
    b.recycle();
    return bd;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one different bitmap object and BitmapDrawable object in each call time, as you said during 12 times, supposing a size of 150kb this is 1800 extra KB in memory only for your Bitmaps. 
Try to reuse your elements (objects, bitmaps and images), and check your memory usage in Android Studio in order to decrease it.

Comment: How does a bitmap of 1*50 pixels take 150KB of memory? Bitmap's memory footprint is still proportional to the size, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's proportional or not, I think it depends on how you do it. Analyze your app memory consumption in Android Studio and you will have a better answer. Here you have more about Bitmaps and memory: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) to request a larger Bitmap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices.

Please add 
`android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest in application tag.

Comment: I'll try that but the thing is, I shouldn't need that. The bitmaps I'm creating are 1*50 pixels, ARGB_8888 is taking for bytes per pixel so the content of all 12 bitmaps only take 2.4KB of memory, plus some metadata, which should only be few bytes!